# which is Perfect position type for Side bar component?

Tags: css, html, css-position, positioning, sidebar

I am developing a side bar component and i have confusion with setting position. in my application position fixed and absolute is working and get suits this application. But i have doubt which one will be perfect match fixed/absolute for side bar component to avoid any further issues and to suits in all application.

Thanks for any advice

Comment: Depends on what you'r trying to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It totally depend on scenario but if u are trying for single page application it's batter to use `position:fixed`